# ¿Cómo insertar información a una tabla, desde APEX, usando un PACKAGE?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, apex

Actualmente estoy insertando información a una tabla, con insert o update values

```
        IF     :P903_PYMT_MTH_ID IS NOT NULL

    THEN
    INSERT INTO "NOMBRE DE LA TABLA" (
                                        PYMT_MTH_ID,
                                        PYMT_MTH_TYPE,
                                        PYMT_MTH_NM,
                                        CRT_DT_TM,
                                        MOD_DT_TM,
                                        USR_NM,
                                        LAST_TXN_DT            
                                          )                                      
    VALUES     (
                    :P903_PYMT_MTH_ID,
                    :P903_PYMT_MTH_TYPE,
                    :P903_PYMT_MTH_NM,
                    sysdate,
                    sysdate,    
                    :P903_USR_NM,
                    :P903_LAST_TXN_DT
               );
               
               COMMIT;
```

Pero ahora me piden que lo haga con un paquete que acaban de crear:

```
PROCEDURE P_NEW(PN_PYMT_MTH_ID        NUMBER,
                 PV_PYMT_MTH_TP        VARCHAR2,
                 PV_PYMT_MTH_NM        VARCHAR2,
                 PV_USR_NM             VARCHAR2,
                 PN_RESULTADO          OUT NUMBER) AS
    VN_EXISTE NUMBER := 0;
 BEGIN

   PN_RESULTADO := 0;

   SELECT COUNT(1) INTO VN_EXISTE
      FROM "NOMBRE DE LA TABLA"
     WHERE PYMT_MTH_ID = PN_PYMT_MTH_ID;
```

¿Cómo hago para enlazar cada ítem con un package? Debo decir que nunca antes he trabajado con paquetes, por lo que no tengo ningún conocimiento de cómo utilizarlos. Gracias de antemano por quienes puedan responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la manera de solventar mi propio problema, a través de otras fuentes. Adjunto abajo la respuesta por si le es de utilidad a alguien con el mismo inconveniente:

```
DECLARE
  log_arg NUMBER;
BEGIN
  NOMBREPKG.P_NEW(PN_PYMT_MTH_ID => :P903_PYMT_MTH_ID,
                 PV_PYMT_MTH_TP => :P903_PYMT_MTH_TYPE,
                 PV_PYMT_MTH_NM => :P903_PYMT_MTH_NM,
                 PV_USR_NM => :P903_USR_NM,
                 PN_RESULTADO => log_arg);
END;
```

"NOMBREPKG" se reemplaza por el nombre del paquete, seguido del punto, que llama al procedimiento en cuestión. Existe la posibilidad de habilitar paquetes en la misma tabla, siempre y cuando este esté en la misma BD de APEX [Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEUTL/managing-methods-on-tables.htm#AEUTL29131)
Sin embargo, yo estaba trabajando con dblink, por lo que no lo pude habilitar, pero es una función bastante práctica.